# What is an elegant way to add dashes in number strings?

Tags: r, regex

I have

```
a = c("1234567890", "0987654321")
```

and I want

```
a = c("123-456-789", "098-765-4321")
```

I want to add dashes in the 4th and 8th place of the string, how can I do that?

Comment: You would need to better define what you want to get as the result. What rules would determine where the dashes go?

Comment: `gsub('(.{3})(.{3})(.*)', '\\1-\\2-\\3', a)`, though there might be a cool way to do it with regex recursion. `substr` and `paste` would also work.

Comment: Yeah, or `gsub("(...)(...)(.*)", "\\1-\\2-\\3", a)`.

Comment: I was trying to use substr(), but can't figure out how to just insert the dash in that position without replacing the digit in that position...

Comment: With `substr` it's be `paste(substr(a, 1, 3), substr(a, 4, 6), substr(a, 7, nchar(a)), sep = '-')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `gsub` (similar to one of the comments) :

```
gsub("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})$","\\1-\\2-\\3",a)
[1] "123-456-7890" "098-765-4321"
```

Or using `str_replace` from `stringr` :

```
str_replace(a,"(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})$","\\1-\\2-\\3")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is there any ways to use substr()?

Comment: @user3697665 yes there is way to use `substr`.

Comment: @user3697665 - You said you wanted elegant.  `substr` is not elegant (or efficient).

Comment: Another `stringr` option with a lookbehind instead of capture groups:  `str_replace_all(a, "(?<=^\\d{3}|^\\d{6})", "-")`